# Sphinx document generator does not like multi-line cell when using Grid Table

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, ascii-art

I read the documentation [here](http://rest-sphinx-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReST.html#tables) about using the Grid Table style when creating a table to display some information via Sphinx document generator. However, my gride table does not behave when formatted. Any ideas why?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| Element Selector                                                                                         | data-*      | data-neuro-* value | Combined                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-button | loMonthly          | data-button='loMonthly'     |
| div.lo.lo__all-offers > div.lo__sortable-header > button.lo__sortable-header--monthly.selected-sort.desc |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-button | loSortBtn          | data-button='loSortBtn'     |
|  div.lo.lo__all-offers > div.lo__sortable-header > button.lo__sortable-header--apr.desc                  |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-button | loInterest         | data-button='loInterest'    |
|  div.lo.lo__all-offers > div.lo__sortable-header > button.lo__sortable-header--interest-paid.desc        |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-button | loTerm             | data-button='loTerm'        |
| div.lo.lo__all-offers > div.lo__sortable-header > button.lo__sortable-header--term-length.desc           |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-region | loFees             | data-region='loFees'        |
| div.lo.lo__all-offers > div.lo__sortable-header > div.lo__sortable-header--fees                          |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-region | loCall             | data-region='loCall'        |
| div.lo.lo__all-offers > a > div > p                                                                      |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-button | LoanOptionBtn      | data-button='LoanOptionBtn' |
| div.lo__drawer-container > div > button                                                                  |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
| #loanOfferSection > div.application-form-section__container > div > form >                               | data-region | CopyText           | data-region='CopyText'      |
| div.lo__drawer-container.show-drawer > div > div.lo__legal-copy                                          |             |                    |                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I would like the Element Selector cells to be short enough that I don't have to scroll horizontally when the docs are generated, but I can't even view it because I get the following error: '(ERROR/3) Malformed table' when I run my make html to create my docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a strange invisible character in the first row and column, preceding the word "Element".  Delete that invisible character, and the table should render.

However I don't think grid tables support column width except when you wrap each cell's content to the relative desired width.  With csv tables, you can use the :widths: attribute to specify how many characters should appear in each column, something like this:

```
.. table:: my table description
   :widths: 40, 10, 15, 30
```